# How can I split date column into date and time in R?

Tags: rstudio

I have this DATE column with Date (20150601) + Hour (02) and so on till the next year. I need to split this one column in two corresponding columns (Date and Hour) in R. As I understand I need stringr package.

What I have

DATE

1. 2015060102
2. 2015060104
3. 2015060106
4. 2015060109
5. 2015060110

Answer (score 0):

If you are just after a column, each of them a string, you can use substr for this task:

```
input_vals <- "2015060102"
date_col <- substr(input_vals, 1, 8)
hour_col <- substr(input_vals, 9, 10)
```